# Showing line number in glossaries

Tags: glossaries

In the glossary, I need to show the "page/line" of each occurrence of a term, e.g.:

```
Glossary

  clamour
    1) plainte, cri. 24/10, 40/5
    2) requête. 50/24, 50/28
```

Would this be possible using the *glossaries* package (or any other package)?

Comment: With `lineno` package it is possible via cross reference, I think.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Leo Liu: yes, with `\linelabel`, but `\linelabel` does not work in display math. So, if the term happened to be inside a display math, the equation number has to be used instead of the line number.

Comment: @g.kov: I think it might not appear in glossary.

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example?

Comment: @g.kov: I don't need any glossary entries inside math. Does it simplify the solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not interested in collating the location lists, the following will work:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[subentrycounter]{glossaries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeglossaries

\newcounter{glslabcount}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \stepcounter{glslabcount}%
  \edef\thislabel{glslab:\arabic{glslabcount}}%
  \expandafter\linelabel\expandafter{\thislabel}%
  \ifcsundef{glsreflist.\glslabel}%
  {\csdef{glsreflist.\glslabel}{}}{}%
  \listcsxadd{glsreflist.\glslabel}{\thislabel}%
  \glsgenentryfmt
}

\newglossaryentry{clamour}{name={clamour},description={}}
\newglossaryentry{clamour1}{parent={clamour},description={plainte, cri}}
\newglossaryentry{clamour2}{parent={clamour},description={requ\^ete}}

\newcommand{\glslisthandler}[1]{%
  \glslisthandlersep
  \pageref{#1}/\ref{#1}%
  \def\glslisthandlersep{, }%
}

\newglossarystyle{pagelineno}%
{%
  \setglossarystyle{index}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
     \ifcsdef{glsreflist.##1}%
     {%
       . 
       \def\glslisthandlersep{}%
       \forlistcsloop{\glslisthandler}{glsreflist.##1}%
     }{}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \ifcase##1\relax
      \item
    \or
      \subitem
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \else
      \subsubitem
    \fi
    \glstarget{##2}%
    \glossentrydesc{##2}.
    \ifcsdef{glsreflist.##2}%
    {%
      \def\glslisthandlersep{}%
      \forlistcsloop{\glslisthandler}{glsreflist.##2}%
    }{}%
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{pagelineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\lipsum*[1] TEST: \gls{clamour1}
\lipsum[2-4]

% Have some entries on a page spanning paragraph:
\lipsum*[5] TEST: \gls{clamour2}
\lipsum*[6] TEST: \gls{clamour1}, \gls{clamour2}.
\lipsum[7]

\lipsum[8]

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The glossary looks like:

[image: Image of glossary]

This works by making a label every time an entry is referenced and storing the label in a list corresponding to that entry. This list is then iterated through when the entry is displayed in the glossary. This just uses `makeindex` to sort the entries. It ignores the real location list. The only problem will be if you have an entry that appears more than once on the same line, as then you'll get a repeated reference.

**Edit:**

For the cross-referenced term, I'm assuming you don't intend to use this term in the document, but just want it to appear in the glossary with the cross-reference. This can be done by editing the style to include the location list only if `\glsreflist.`*label* hasn't been defined:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[subentrycounter]{glossaries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeglossaries

\newcounter{glslabcount}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \stepcounter{glslabcount}%
  \edef\thislabel{glslab:\arabic{glslabcount}}%
  \expandafter\linelabel\expandafter{\thislabel}%
  \ifcsundef{glsreflist.\glslabel}%
  {\csdef{glsreflist.\glslabel}{}}{}%
  \listcsxadd{glsreflist.\glslabel}{\thislabel}%
  \glsgenentryfmt
}

\newglossaryentry{clamour}{name={clamour},description={}}
\newglossaryentry{clamour1}{parent={clamour},description={plainte,
cri}}
\newglossaryentry{clamour2}{parent={clamour},description={requ\^ete}}

\newglossaryentry{cri}{name={cri},description={bla bla},see=[voir]{clamour}}

\newcommand{\glslisthandler}[1]{%
  \glslisthandlersep
  \pageref{#1}/\ref{#1}%
  \def\glslisthandlersep{, }%
}

\newglossarystyle{pagelineno}%
{%
  \setglossarystyle{index}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
     \ifcsdef{glsreflist.##1}%
     {%
       . 
       \def\glslisthandlersep{}%
       \forlistcsloop{\glslisthandler}{glsreflist.##1}%
     }%
     {, ##2}% <- add location list to ensure cross-reference is included
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \ifcase##1\relax
      \item
    \or
      \subitem
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \else
      \subsubitem
    \fi
    \glstarget{##2}%
    \glossentrydesc{##2}.
    \ifcsdef{glsreflist.##2}%
    {%
      \def\glslisthandlersep{}%
      \forlistcsloop{\glslisthandler}{glsreflist.##2}%
    }{}%
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{pagelineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\lipsum*[1] TEST: \gls{clamour1}
\lipsum[2-4]

% Have some entries on a page spanning paragraph:
\lipsum*[5] TEST: \gls{clamour2}
\lipsum*[6] TEST: \gls{clamour1}, \gls{clamour2}.
\lipsum[7]

\lipsum[8]

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The glossary now looks like:

[image: Image of glossary]

Comment: It works as expected, thanks! I am now trying to add an entry with a "see" reference, e.g.: `\newglossaryentry{cri}{name={cri},description={bla bla},see=[voir]{clamour}}`, but "see" is being ignored by the custom style, could you please advise?

Comment: @dgaspar I've added an extra example.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. Here is one approach. We use package `lineno` to do the line numbering. Then we convince the `glossaries` package to write `<pagenumber>.<linenumber>` into the raw index file. As the line number is not known when we typeset a particular glossary term in the text, we have to write the running line counter, and compute the page-wise line number from that when we typeset the glossary. To do so, we use the built-in macros of `glossaries` to dissect the location list. These macros exist for usage with `hyperref`, but we force `glossaries` to use them even without `hyperref`. In the final step, when only the composite page number is to be typeset with `\@gls@numberlink`, we make the page number into a link if desired, and compute the correct page-wise line number of the glossary term.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage[subentrycounter]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-tree}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeglossaries
%% number sub entries with a), b) etc.
\renewcommand*{\glssubentrycounterlabel}{\alph{glossarysubentry})\space}

\makeatletter
%% write the running line number into the source index file
\patchcmd{\@@do@wrglossary}
  {\protected@xdef\@glslocref{\theglsentrycounter}}
  {\protected@xdef\@glslocref{\theglsentrycounter.\thelinenumber}}
  {}{\message{^^JPatching failed^^J}}

%% If we feed the page list (containing \delimR ranges or \delimN enumerations)
%% to \glshypernumber (even without hyperref),
%% we end up being our composite numbers (page.line) being fed to
%% \@glshypernumber, thus to \@gls@numberlink
\renewcommand{\glsnumberformat}[1]{%
  \glshypernumber{#1}}

\def\glshypernumber#1{\@glshypernumber#1\nohyperpage{}\@nil}
%% in case hyperref is not loaded, make \hyperlink just write the link text
\providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{#2}

\let\orig@gls@numberlink\@gls@numberlink
\renewcommand{\@gls@numberlink}[1]{%
  \myformatnumb#1\@nil}

\def\myformatnumb#1.#2\@nil{%
  \orig@gls@numberlink{#1}/\getpagewiselinenumber{#2}}

\makeatother

%% a main entry and two sub-entries
\newglossaryentry{clamour}{%
  name = {clamour},
  description = {\nopostdesc},
}
\newglossaryentry{plainte}{%
  parent = clamour,
  name = {plainte, cri},
  description = {\nopostdesc},
}
\newglossaryentry{requete}{%
  parent = clamour,
  name = {requ\^ete},
  description={\nopostdesc},
}

\pagewiselinenumbers

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\gls{plainte}

\lipsum[3-4]
\gls{requete}

\lipsum[5-6]
\gls{requete}

\gls{requete}

\gls{requete}

\lipsum[7-8]
\gls{plainte}

\nolinenumbers%
\printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: This seems to work correctly only when the glossed terms appear at the beginnings of paragraphs. When this is not the case, the line number references in the glossary are incorrect. In your example, if you simply change `\usepackage{lipsum}` to `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}`, so that not all of the `\gls` entries begin a paragraph, the line numbers in the glossary will be inaccurate.

Comment: @JeffreyBarnes You are right. Need to investigate further.

Comment: Do you think you could come up with a simple fix to show the actual line number when inside a paragraph?